# Devolver varios registros con EntityFramework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, datagridview

Tengo el siguiente código que me devuelve el primer elemento en base a la consulta que se realiza y lo presente en un `Datagridview`, pero si encuentro el caso que debe devolver varios registros como podría realizarlo.

```
 public void Obtener_Presupuesto_Version_Do(String sValue, DataGridView dataGridPre, TextBox subtotal, TextBox pordscsub, TextBox totdscsub,
     TextBox portarsub, TextBox tottarsub, TextBox total)
    {
        try
        {
            using (DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES db = new DIENTES_SANOS_ENTITIES())
            {
                var pre = db.TBL_PRESUPUESTO.Where(a => a.PRE_COD == sValue).OrderBy(a => a.PRE_ID).FirstOrDefault();
                if (pre != null)
                {
                    String pre_cod = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_COD);
                    String pre_cod_pac = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_COD_PAC);
                    String pre_nom_pac = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_NOM_PAC);
                    String pre_cod_odon = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_COD_ODON);
                    String pre_nom_odon = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_NOM_ODON);
                    String pre_rut = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_RUT);
                    String pre_den_pac = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_DEN_PAC);
                    String pre_pie_den = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_PIE_DEN);
                    String pre_tra_pac = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_TRA_PAC);
                    Double pre_val_pre = Convert.ToDouble(pre.PRE_VAL_PRE);
                    Double pre_val_por = Convert.ToDouble(pre.PRE_VAL_POR);
                    Double pre_val_des = Convert.ToDouble(pre.PRE_VAL_DES);
                    Double pre_val_sub = Convert.ToDouble(pre.PRE_VAL_SUB);
                    Double pre_val_por_dsc_sub = Convert.ToDouble(pre.PRE_VAL_POR_DSC_SUB);
                    Double pre_val_tot_dsc_sub = Convert.ToDouble(pre.PRE_VAL_TOT_DSC_SUB);
                    int pre_val_por_tar_sub = Convert.ToInt16(pre.PRE_VAL_POR_TAR_SUB);
                    Double pre_val_tot_tar_sub = Convert.ToDouble(pre.PRE_VAL_TOT_TAR_SUB);
                    Double pre_val_tot = Convert.ToDouble(pre.PRE_VAL_TOT);
                    int pre_id = Convert.ToInt32(pre.PRE_ID);
                    String pre_fec_ela = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_ELA_PRE);
                    String pre_fec_rea = Convert.ToString(pre.PRE_EST_REA);
                    _ = dataGridPre.Rows.Add(pre_cod, pre_cod_pac, pre_nom_pac, pre_cod_odon, pre_nom_odon, pre_rut, pre_den_pac, pre_pie_den, pre_tra_pac, pre_val_pre, pre_val_por, pre_val_des, pre_val_sub, pre_id, pre_fec_ela, pre_fec_rea);
                    subtotal.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_sub);
                    pordscsub.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_por_dsc_sub);
                    totdscsub.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_tot_dsc_sub);
                    portarsub.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_por_tar_sub);
                    tottarsub.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_tot_tar_sub);
                    total.Text = Convert.ToString(pre_val_tot);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _ = MessageBox.Show("ERROR: " + ex.Message, "ERROR!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Me parece que tu código debiera ser:

```
dataGrid.DataSource = db.TBL_PRESUPUESTO.Where(a => a.PRE_COD == sValue).OrderBy(a => a.PRE_ID).ToList();
```

Pones el resultado de la consulta **Linq** directamente en la **propiedad DataSource** del **DataGrid**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: Efectivamente era lo que necesitaba, solo le a;adi unos cambios para que se ajuste las columnas y llamar mediante select solo las columnas que necesito que se visualicen, de antemano gracias campeon.